# Get notified when MacOS goes to sleep

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, sleep

I successfully get NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification when I force my Mac to go to sleep: this notification, though, doesn't raise if my computer goes to sleep by itself after a certain amount of time, specified in the energy preferences.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Seems odd that NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification doesn't get fired for idle sleep... Are you filing with the default notification center instead of NSWorkspace's notification center (you need to file with the latter). Otherwise, you could set up a callback for  I/O Kit sleep/wake notifications (see [http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html))

Comment: I'm using NSWorkspace's notification center. Just to know: do you experience the same bug or it works, for you?

Comment: I just did a quick test, and it looks like on 10.7.4, idle sleep notifications don't get sent by NSWorkspace unless someone has called IORegisterForSystemPower, while on 10.6.8, they get sent no matter what. Now, I only tested on a handful of machines, so it's possible that it's a difference in hardware, system settings, or even the presence of some other app that's called IORegisterForSystemPower, so don't trust the details too far. But it is at least some confirmation that sometimes the notifications don't get sent. Test whether IORegisterForSystemPower solves the problem.

Comment: And if IORegisterForSystemPower does solve the problem, it strikes me that, having written the code for that, you might as well use it and not bother with the NSWorkspace notifications. (That way, you can distinguish between forced and idle sleep, etc.) The code in QA1340 can be copied and pasted directly into a Cocoa app's -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] as long as you leave out the CFRunLoopRun.

Comment: Thank you for your (much appreciated) help, I'll take a look at IORegisterForSystemPower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I've been able to reproduce this on some computers but not others. From a very quick investigation, it looks like 10.7.4 doesn't send the notification on idle sleep unless I've also called IORegisterForSystemPower, but 10.6.8 does. So, it could be a bug in 10.7. But, since my testing was pretty minimal, it could also be a bug in a specific hardware model, or something to do with strange settings that I didn't think of.

On the other hand, this could be intentional behavior—in which case I think there's a bug in the documentation. While it doesn't directly say that the notification is sent for both idle and forced sleep, but it certainly implies it.

The NSWorkspace notifications reference (can't get a URL because developer.apple.com seems to be down…) says it's "posted before the machine goes to sleep"—not "sometimes" or "only for forced sleep".

QA1340 (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) discusses both kinds of sleep, and says that Cocoa can be used to receive notifications, without any hint that it only works for one kind. It gives sample code that should work, and that's what I used to reproduce the problem.

I'd strongly suggest filing a bug report with Apple, copying your bug report to http://openradar.appspot.com, and opening a thread on Apple's dev forums. And, if you're a paid MDP member, try it on 10.8DP4.1, and start a thread in the NDA section of the dev forums. If 10.8 is still broken, your radar might lead to Apple fixing it before the final release, while it's unlikely to be fixed if nobody reports it.

Comment: For the record, I have just tried the Cocoa-approach described in QA1340, and it works for idle sleep.

Comment: You see I'm also at a stage to use this. Could you pls explain how you did it. My application is coded in Java and I need to collect data every time my Mac sleeps and wakes.  I have this code but has no idea how to use this objective c code for my java coded application.